# How to refer collections in mongo db?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to Mongo database,

I am using node.js mongoose library in my project. My requirement is

I have two collections. 1. services 2. packages

1. services contains only one values i.e service_name
2. packages contains 3 values 1. package_name(string), 2. array of services(array of first collection services), 3. duration(time)

From the above two collection, first Collection  Services contains 100 documents, when inserting documents into second collection Packages, the second value should refer to first collection.

I want to refer services collection from package collection?

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Package', new Schema({
    packageName:   { type: String, unique: true },
    services: {id:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'service'}}, // Am I doing wrong here?
    duration: { type: Date, default: Date.now}
}));

module.exports = mongoose.model('Service', new Schema({
   service:   { type: String, unique: true }
}));
```

Can anyone please provide me the correct way of defining models and accessing them?

Comment: load all records from services, and reference those with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

try this , this is correct way design the schema in mongoose

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Service', new Schema({
   service:   { type: String, unique: true }
}));
```

your package model

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Package', new Schema({
    packageName:   { type: String, unique: true },
    services: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'service'}], // Array of service
    duration: { type: Date, default: Date.now}
}));
```

another way

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Package', new Schema({
        packageName:   { type: String, unique: true },
        services: [{serviceId:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'service'}}], // Array of service
        duration: { type: Date, default: Date.now}
    }));
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply Karthi, Instead of referring service ObjectId I want to refer complete service object. While inserting into the package model I will insert complete service object. I had tried the below code, But it is throwing cast error, 
var service = require('./service')

module.exports = mongoose.model('Package', new Schema({
 packageName:   { type: String, unique: true },
 services: [service],
 duration: { type: Date, default: Date.now}
}));

Can you please let me know, what is correct procedure for referring complete service collection?

Comment: i post the ans and cast error is model field type is wrong , like String ,Number ect

Answer (score 0):

first design service schema

```
var serviceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     service:   { type: String, unique: true }
});
```

then design package maodel

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Package', new Schema({
    packageName:   { type: String, unique: true },
    services: [serviceSchema], // Array of service object
    duration: { type: Date, default: Date.now}
}));
```

Comment: Thank you karthi, It works. I was using model instead of schema